# Multiple conditions on single button with Dynamic Action in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-18.2, oracle-apex-19.1

Please see below screen shot I have one button "Add Row" on the top and items in a single row of Oracle Apex Form.
I have add 10 Rows with same items list on each click of the top button. Could you please help on this how can I achieve this.
[image]
[image]

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0DT8.png]

Comment: You haven't given us much to go on here, other than a screenshot. Your title mentions "conditions", but I don't think this is related to conditions. You want to add more rows to a region, right? What type of form is this? How did you create it? What happens when you hit submit (how is it processed)?

Comment: Thanks for replying, in the row items are there which I put manually.
So same set of items will be repeatd after each click on a button otherwise only single row will be shown when the page loads

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you correctly and you want a dynamically determined amount of files to upload, there are many options for that

Easiest 1 - upload one at a time, and show the user older files that were uploaded.

Easiest 2 - Use the "Allow multiple files" option, and later on allow the user to edit names
https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2016/08/file-upload-improvements-in-apex-5-1/

Easy option:
Create a modal dialog form page for uploading the documents, and make the "add row" button a link to open that modal dialog page.

Harder option:
Using the APEX_ITEM package, and dynamic actions:
https://dzone.com/articles/super-dynamic-apex-forms-using-apex-item-and-dynam

If on the other hand you know you're always going to have 10 items uploaded, I suggest just creating them all in the app builder, and save time..

Comment: Could you please have a look on the ss I attached recently, also I can move from the design that is the issue nor I have Apex v5 to user multiple file upload functionality. I want to put condition in one button for each row to be displayed on by one. By seeing ss you can understand the requirement. please help here if you can.

Comment: also I have to put cancel button for wach row, basically its like a tabular form deleting and adding rows not to db on the browser itself

Comment: I suggest the following:
create a hidden item "P1_DOCUMENTS_COUNT" with default of 1. use JS too increase it when users clicks the button "add row".
Create 10 times the following row of items (# for the row number):
P1_DOC_DATE_#, P1_DOC_DESCRIPTION_#, P1_DOC_NAME_#, P1_DOC_CATEGORY_#, P1_DOC_FILE_BROWSER_#. at the beginning - rows 2-9 will be hidden. when P1_DOCUMENTS_COUNT = n, show rows 1,2,...n.

Comment: what happens when some deletes a row in between...?

Comment: I appreciate yor answer over my concern, however I have used plsql for increment instead of js.... thank you so much... I have further query on delete button for each row which I posted in as another question please check it would be great if you could help here...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61369931/looking-for-plsql-code-based-on-oracle-apex-layout-design